# Differentiable+Not monotone

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a real function that is differentiable at any point but nowhere monotone?

Comment: the constant function works, but I assume that example should be disallowed.

Comment: Doesn't "monotone" by default mean weakly, not strictly, monotone? (i.e. monotone increasing means for all $x$, $y$, $x \le y \Rightarrow f(x) \le f(y)$). So constant functions are everywhere monotone.

Comment: See also the [MO version](http://mathoverflow.net/q/167323/6085) of this question for additional details and references.

Comment: And see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/802647/462) for details of the Katznelson-Stromberg construction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. See for example "Everywhere Differentiable, Nowhere Monotone, Functions" by Y. Katznelson and Karl Stromberg.

Comment: The link doesn't work; is it just me?

Comment: @Jonas: Google katznelson-stromberg.pdf and then click on "Quick view" on the first result.

Comment: The link above seems broken as well. Anyway, details have been posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/802647/462).