# Monotonicity in an interval

Tags: analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)<0$. Does this imply that $\exists$$\delta>0$ such that f is monotonic in $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f$ to be $x+2x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $0$ at $x=0$.  This is an example of a function that has a positive derivative, but is not monotonic on any open interval surrounding that point.  Now just multiply it by $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no. Here is an example:
$$
f(x) = -x^2(2+\sin(1/x)), \qquad f(0)=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Define $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 -\sin(x) &\mbox{ if $x$ is rational} \\
 - x &\mbox{ otherwise}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are even differentiable functions that are not monotone on any interval, as seen in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17067).