# Positive derivative at $c$, then $f(x)>f(c)$ for close $x>c$

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** Let $f$ be defined on an open interval $(a, b)$ and assume that for some $c \in (a, b)$ $f^{\prime} (c)> 0$ then show that there is a open ball around $c$, say $B(c) \subseteq (a, b)$ in which $f(x)> f(c)$ if $x>c$ and $f(x)< f(c)$ if $x<c$. Note:  $f^{\prime}$ denotes the derivative of the function $f$.

What I have understood is that I have to show that function $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval $(a, b)$. Given that $f^{\prime} (c)> 0$ which implies that $f$ must be differentiable. Now, I am trying to apply the Lagrange mean value theorem. But I am not sure which interval to take so that I can prove desired inequality. Also, how can I introduce open ball around $c$ so that $B(c) \subseteq (a, b)$ and desired inequality holds true there.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $f$ need not be increasing in any interval surrounding $c$.  The result here follows directly from the definition of the derivative at $c$.

$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} =f'(c)>0$,

which implies that when $x$ is sufficiently close to $c$, i.e. for $x$ in some interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ is positive.  For $x>c$, this implies $f(x)>f(c)$.  For $x<c$, this implies $f(x)<f(c)$.

To see why you can't show $f$ is increasing in an interval, see [Differentiable+Not monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/differentiablenot-monotone). Even though the link doesn't work in the answer, hopefully the reference given or the comments or googling will lead you to more info if you're interested.

---

For just a particular point like you're asking about, $f(x) = x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$ (and $f(0)=0$) provides an example where $f$ is not monotone in any interval containing $0$, although $f'(0)=1$.  When $x\neq 0$ we have $f'(x)=1+4x\sin(1/x)-2\cos(1/x)$, which is negative arbitrarily close to $0$, e.g. when $x=\dfrac{1}{2\pi n}$ for each nonzero integer $n$.  By the same reasoning as in the solution to your problem, this implies that $f$ can't be increasing in any interval containing a $\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$, while every interval containing $0$ has infinitely many of these.  Without using derivatives, you can verify that when $n$ is sufficiently large, $f\left(\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}\right)-f\left(\dfrac1{2n\pi+\frac\pi2}\right)<0$.

Comment: Thank you for very clear answer. I fully understood. I have just one doubt. What is the difference between this condition  $f(x)> f(c)$ if $x>c$, around certain ball at $c$ and definition of monotonic function? Thank you again.

Comment: It means the values to the right are bigger than $f(c)$, but they don't stay in order relative to each other.  You can have $c<x<y<c+\delta$ where $\delta $ is small enough to ensure that $f(x)>f(c)$ and $f(y)>c$, even though $f(x)>f(y)$, and there are examples where this can happen no matter how small $\delta$ is.  The other question is for really dramatic cases of this. I might add a concrete example for just a particular $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and an elegant answer. As for now, I am not able to construct such an example but your statement is very convincing to me. Thank you again.

Comment: @srijan: I added an example.

Comment: I am clear now. At one point, I think you mean $f^{\prime}(x) = 1+4x\sin(1/x)-2\cos(1/x)$ is non negative$? Am I right?. A sincere thanks from my side dear professor.

Comment: @srijan: No, I mean that arbitarily close to $0$ there are values of $x$ such that $f'(x)<0$, and then specifically note that you can take $x=1/(2n\pi)$ to see this.  This is true even though $f'(0)=1$.  You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you got your point.  I didn,t pay attention to $x$. No more confusion. :)